# Apostrophe (') in XPath query

Tags: c#, java, xml, xpath

I use the following `XPATH Query` to list the object under a site. `ListObject[@Title='SomeValue']`. SomeValue is dynamic. This query works as long as SomeValue does not have an apostrophe ('). Tried using escape sequence also. Didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: so is SomeValue a C# variable?

Comment: Yes. It is a C# Variable."ListObject[@Title='" + SomeValue +"']". This is how I have written the expression

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This is surprisingly difficult to do.

Take a look at the [XPath Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath), and you'll see that it defines a literal as:

```
Literal ::=   '"' [^"]* '"' 
            | "'" [^']* "'"
```

Which is to say, string literals in XPath expressions can contain apostrophes or double quotes but not both.

You can't use escaping to get around this.  A literal like this:

```
'Some&apos;Value'
```

will match this XML text:

```
Some&amp;apos;Value
```

This does mean that it's possible for there to be a piece of XML text that you can't generate an XPath literal to match, e.g.:

```
<elm att="&quot;&apos"/>
```

But that doesn't mean it's impossible to match that text with XPath, it's just tricky.  In any case where the value you're trying to match contains both single and double quotes, you can construct an expression that uses `concat` to produce the text that it's going to match:

```
elm[@att=concat('"', "'")]
```

So that leads us to this, which is a lot more complicated than I'd like it to be:

```
/// <summary>
/// Produce an XPath literal equal to the value if possible; if not, produce
/// an XPath expression that will match the value.
/// 
/// Note that this function will produce very long XPath expressions if a value
/// contains a long run of double quotes.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value">The value to match.</param>
/// <returns>If the value contains only single or double quotes, an XPath
/// literal equal to the value.  If it contains both, an XPath expression,
/// using concat(), that evaluates to the value.</returns>
static string XPathLiteral(string value)
{
    // if the value contains only single or double quotes, construct
    // an XPath literal
    if (!value.Contains("\""))
    {
        return "\"" + value + "\"";
    }
    if (!value.Contains("'"))
    {
        return "'" + value + "'";
    }

    // if the value contains both single and double quotes, construct an
    // expression that concatenates all non-double-quote substrings with
    // the quotes, e.g.:
    //
    //    concat("foo", '"', "bar")
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("concat(");
    string[] substrings = value.Split('\"');
    for (int i = 0; i < substrings.Length; i++ )
    {
        bool needComma = (i>0);
        if (substrings[i] != "")
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                sb.Append(", ");
            }
            sb.Append("\"");
            sb.Append(substrings[i]);
            sb.Append("\"");
            needComma = true;
        }
        if (i < substrings.Length - 1)
        {
            if (needComma)
            {
                sb.Append(", ");                    
            }
            sb.Append("'\"'");
        }

    }
    sb.Append(")");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

And yes, I tested it with all the edge cases.  That's why the logic is so stupidly complex:

```
    foreach (string s in new[]
    {
        "foo",              // no quotes
        "\"foo",            // double quotes only
        "'foo",             // single quotes only
        "'foo\"bar",        // both; double quotes in mid-string
        "'foo\"bar\"baz",   // multiple double quotes in mid-string
        "'foo\"",           // string ends with double quotes
        "'foo\"\"",         // string ends with run of double quotes
        "\"'foo",           // string begins with double quotes
        "\"\"'foo",         // string begins with run of double quotes
        "'foo\"\"bar"       // run of double quotes in mid-string
    })
    {
        Console.Write(s);
        Console.Write(" = ");
        Console.WriteLine(XPathLiteral(s));
        XmlElement elm = d.CreateElement("test");
        d.DocumentElement.AppendChild(elm);
        elm.SetAttribute("value", s);

        string xpath = "/root/test[@value = " + XPathLiteral(s) + "]";
        if (d.SelectSingleNode(xpath) == elm)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OK");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Should have found a match for {0}, and didn't.", s);
        }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Please do.  I actually have no use for it myself; I only did this because at first I found the problem interesting and then as I dug in its difficulty started to annoy me.  My ADHD is your gain.

Comment: How is about "\n"? I have doubt new lines could cause problems too.

Comment: @kan no, it's perfectly fine for a string literal in XPath to contain a newline character.  The _only_ restriction is that single quoted literals can't contain single quotes and double quoted literals can't contain double quotes.

Comment: _"This is surprisingly difficult to do."_ It's only surprisingly difficult to do if you go about it the wrong way (by trying to cobble strings together). If you use one of the right approaches, it's pretty simple.

Comment: Hi @RobertRossney I'm facing the same problem, i have my search string as "???" and "+". I'm able to find all except these two. Can you please suggest something for the same.

Comment: awesome work @RobertRossney ! btw, i did a PHP port of this code, if anyone is interested: https://gist.github.com/divinity76/64b0c12bcafc2150efa8ca87d2ccee52

Comment: pretty sure this can be shortened to a <strike>sweet</strike> one-liner, eg PHP: ```function xpath_quote($str){ return 'concat(\''.implode('\', "\'", \'', explode('\'', $value)).'\')'; }``` - generates less efficient, longer xpaths in most situations, but the code is short<strike>&sweet</strike>: https://3v4l.org/rDa1L

Comment: Made an attempt at upstreaming DOMXPath::quote() in PHP: https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/13456

Answer (score 7):

I ported Robert's answer to Java (tested in 1.6):

```
/// <summary>
/// Produce an XPath literal equal to the value if possible; if not, produce
/// an XPath expression that will match the value.
///
/// Note that this function will produce very long XPath expressions if a value
/// contains a long run of double quotes.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value">The value to match.</param>
/// <returns>If the value contains only single or double quotes, an XPath
/// literal equal to the value.  If it contains both, an XPath expression,
/// using concat(), that evaluates to the value.</returns>
public static String XPathLiteral(String value) {
    if(!value.contains("\"") && !value.contains("'")) {
        return "'" + value + "'";
    }
    // if the value contains only single or double quotes, construct
    // an XPath literal
    if (!value.contains("\"")) {
        System.out.println("Doesn't contain Quotes");
        String s = "\"" + value + "\"";
        System.out.println(s);
        return s;
    }
    if (!value.contains("'")) {
        System.out.println("Doesn't contain apostophes");
        String s =  "'" + value + "'";
        System.out.println(s);
        return s;
    }

    // if the value contains both single and double quotes, construct an
    // expression that concatenates all non-double-quote substrings with
    // the quotes, e.g.:
    //
    //    concat("foo", '"', "bar")
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("concat(");
    String[] substrings = value.split("\"");
    for (int i = 0; i < substrings.length; i++) {
        boolean needComma = (i > 0);
        if (!substrings[i].equals("")) {
            if (i > 0) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
            sb.append("\"");
            sb.append(substrings[i]);
            sb.append("\"");
            needComma = true;
        }
        if (i < substrings.length - 1) {
            if (needComma) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
            sb.append("'\"'");
        }
        System.out.println("Step " + i + ": " + sb.toString());
    }
    //This stuff is because Java is being stupid about splitting strings
    if(value.endsWith("\"")) {
        sb.append(", '\"'");
    }
    //The code works if the string ends in a apos
    /*else if(value.endsWith("'")) {
        sb.append(", \"'\"");
    }*/
    sb.append(")");
    String s = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(s);
    return s;
}
```

Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT:** After a heavy unit testing session, and checking the [XPath Standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#exprlex), I have revised my function as follows:

```
public static string ToXPath(string value) {

    const string apostrophe = "'";
    const string quote = "\"";

    if(value.Contains(quote)) {
        if(value.Contains(apostrophe)) {
            throw new XPathException("Illegal XPath string literal.");
        } else {
            return apostrophe + value + apostrophe;
        }
    } else {
        return quote + value + quote;
    }
}
```

It appears that XPath doesn't have a character escaping system at all, it's quite primitive really. Evidently my original code only worked by coincidence. My apologies for misleading anyone!

**Original answer below for reference only - please ignore**

For safety, make sure that any occurrence of all 5 predefined XML entities in your XPath string are escaped, e.g.

```
public static string ToXPath(string value) {
    return "'" + XmlEncode(value) + "'";
}

public static string XmlEncode(string value) {
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(value);
    text.Replace("&", "&amp;");
    text.Replace("'", "&apos;");
    text.Replace(@"""", "&quot;");
    text.Replace("<", "&lt;");
    text.Replace(">", "&gt;");
    return text.ToString();
}
```

I have done this before and it works fine. If it doesn't work for you, maybe there is some additional context to the problem that you need to make us aware of.

Comment: You shouldn't even have to treat XML as a plain string. Things like escaping and unescaping are abstracted away for you by the built-in XML libraries. You're reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: If you could point me to a BCL class that abstracts away the process of building an XPath query string, I would gladly ditch these functions.

Comment: Such as `System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(value)`? (in C#)

Comment: @ChristianHayter I'm very late to the party here, but the point you've missed (and that I think Welbog was trying to make) is that XPath has the concept of variables, which are immune to these string delimeter problems. So the best practice is to make use of them. .NET does provide a mechanism for using variables in XPath and I've provided an example of how to do so [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19704008/1945651).

Comment: @JLRishe: I hadn't looked at this question for years; I have not written any XPath queries at all since LINQ to XML came out. :-) Parameterising the data values is always the best solution to any string injection problem, so I have upvoted both your answers. Thanks very much.

Comment: the exception is not necessary, you can work around it [by using concat(), see Robert Rossney's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1352556/1067003)

Answer (score 5):

By far the best approach to this problem is to use the facilities provided by your XPath library to declare an XPath-level variable that you can reference in the expression.  The variable value can then be any string in the host programming language, and isn't subject to the restrictions of XPath string literals.  For example, in Java with `javax.xml.xpath`:

```
XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
final Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<>();
xpf.setXPathVariableResolver(new XPathVariableResolver() {
  public Object resolveVariable(QName name) {
    return variables.get(name.getLocalPart());
  }
});

XPath xpath = xpf.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("ListObject[@Title=$val]");
variables.put("val", someValue);
NodeList nodes = (NodeList)expr.evaluate(someNode, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

For C# `XPathNavigator` you would define a custom `XsltContext` [as described in this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd567715%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (you'd only need the variable-related parts of this example, not the extension functions).

Comment: This _is_ by far the best approach. +1

Answer (score 4):

Most of the answers here focus on how to use string manipulation to cobble together an XPath that uses string delimiters in a valid way.

I would say the best practice is not to rely on such complicated and potentially fragile methods.

The following applies to .NET since this question is tagged with C#. Ian Roberts has provided what I think is the best solution for when you're using XPath in Java.

Nowadays, you can use Linq-to-Xml to query XML documents in a way that allows you to use your variables in the query directly. This is not XPath, but the purpose is the same.

For the example given in OP, you could query the nodes you want like this:

```
var value = "Some value with 'apostrophes' and \"quotes\"";

// doc is an instance of XElement or XDocument
IEnumerable<XElement> nodes = 
                      doc.Descendants("ListObject")
                         .Where(lo => (string)lo.Attribute("Title") == value);
```

or to use the query comprehension syntax:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> nodes = from lo in doc.Descendants("ListObject")
                              where (string)lo.Attribute("Title") == value
                              select lo;
```

.NET also provides a way to use XPath variables in your XPath queries. Sadly, it's not easy to do this out of the box, but with a simple helper class that I provide in [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19704008/1945651), it's quite easy.

You can use it like this:

```
var value = "Some value with 'apostrophes' and \"quotes\"";

var variableContext = new VariableContext { { "matchValue", value } };
// ixn is an instance of IXPathNavigable
XPathNodeIterator nodes = ixn.CreateNavigator()
                             .SelectNodes("ListObject[@Title = $matchValue]", 
                                          variableContext);
```

Comment: I think you have an excellent point, and this is an excellent alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative to Robert Rossney's StringBuilder approach, perhaps more intuitive:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Produce an XPath literal equal to the value if possible; if not, produce
    /// an XPath expression that will match the value.
    /// 
    /// Note that this function will produce very long XPath expressions if a value
    /// contains a long run of double quotes.
    /// 
    /// From: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341847/special-character-in-xpath-query
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value to match.</param>
    /// <returns>If the value contains only single or double quotes, an XPath
    /// literal equal to the value.  If it contains both, an XPath expression,
    /// using concat(), that evaluates to the value.</returns>
    public static string XPathLiteral(string value)
    {
        // If the value contains only single or double quotes, construct
        // an XPath literal
        if (!value.Contains("\""))
            return "\"" + value + "\"";

        if (!value.Contains("'"))
            return "'" + value + "'";

        // If the value contains both single and double quotes, construct an
        // expression that concatenates all non-double-quote substrings with
        // the quotes, e.g.:
        //
        //    concat("foo",'"',"bar")

        List<string> parts = new List<string>();

        // First, put a '"' after each component in the string.
        foreach (var str in value.Split('"'))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                parts.Add('"' + str + '"'); // (edited -- thanks Daniel :-)

            parts.Add("'\"'");
        }

        // Then remove the extra '"' after the last component.
        parts.RemoveAt(parts.Count - 1);

        // Finally, put it together into a concat() function call.
        return "concat(" + string.Join(",", parts) + ")";
    }
```

Comment: fyi yours does not pass all of his tests.

Comment: change your add to the parts to quote the string.

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed that. Fixed. :-)

Comment: Hello Your code is 1000 times better than the original but still more clumsy than required. Instead of first adding a string which you later remove it would be easier:

String[] split = value.Split('"');
for (int i=0; i<split.length; i++)
{
    if (i>0) parts.Add("'\"'");

    if (split[i].Length > 0)
       parts.Add('"' + split[i] + '"');
}

Comment: @Elmue That's a matter of personal taste, I suppose. I find that clunkier than removing the final string. There's no significant difference in performance, of course. Another way to implement it might be to add a '"' *before* each entry, and then use an inline LINQ expression instead of having a separate .Remove statement:

`foreach (var str in value.Split('"'))  
{  
  parts.Add("'\"'");  
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))  
    parts.Add('"' + str + '"');  
}  
      
return "concat(" + string.Join(",", parts.Skip(1)) + ")";`

Comment: @Elmue Thanks for the compliment, by the way :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can quote an XPath string by using search and replace.

In F#

```
let quoteString (s : string) =
    if      not (s.Contains "'" ) then sprintf "'%s'"   s
    else if not (s.Contains "\"") then sprintf "\"%s\"" s
    else "concat('" + s.Replace ("'", "', \"'\", '") + "')"
```

I haven't tested it extensively, but seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I really like [Robert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1352556/9096919), but I feel like the code could be a little denser.

```
using System.Linq;

namespace Humig.Csp.Common
{
    public static class XpathHelpers
    {
        public static string XpathLiteralEncode(string literalValue)
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(literalValue)
                ? "''"
                : !literalValue.Contains("\"")
                ? $"\"{literalValue}\""
                : !literalValue.Contains("'")
                ? $"'{literalValue}'"
                : $"concat({string.Join(",'\"',", literalValue.Split('"').Select(k => $"\"{k}\""))})";
        }
    }
}
```

I have also created a unit test with all the test cases:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace Humig.Csp.Common.Tests
{
    [TestClass()]
    public class XpathHelpersTests
    {

        [DataRow("foo")]   // no quotes
        [DataRow("\"foo")]   // double quotes only
        [DataRow("'foo")]   // single quotes only
        [DataRow("'foo\"bar")]   // both; double quotes in mid-string
        [DataRow("'foo\"bar\"baz")]   // multiple double quotes in mid-string
        [DataRow("'foo\"")]   // string ends with double quotes
        [DataRow("'foo\"\"")]   // string ends with run of double quotes
        [DataRow("\"'foo")]   // string begins with double quotes
        [DataRow("\"\"'foo")]   // string begins with run of double quotes
        [DataRow("'foo\"\"bar")]   // run of double quotes in mid-string
        [TestMethod()]
        public void XpathLiteralEncodeTest(string attrValue)
        {
            var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            var hnode = doc.CreateElement("html");
            var body = doc.CreateElement("body");
            var div = doc.CreateElement("div");
            div.Attributes.Add("data-test", attrValue);
            doc.DocumentNode.AppendChild(hnode);
            hnode.AppendChild(body);
            body.AppendChild(div);
            var literalOut = XpathHelpers.XpathLiteralEncode(attrValue);
            string xpath = $"/html/body/div[@data-test = {literalOut}]";
            var result = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
            Assert.AreEqual(div, result, $"did not find a match for {attrValue}");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going to have any double-quotes in SomeValue, you can use escaped double-quotes to specify the value you're searching for in your XPath search string.

```
ListObject[@Title=\"SomeValue\"]
```

Comment: That's not how you escape characters in XML.

Comment: That's true.  But an XPath query isn't XML text, and at any rate he's not escaping the quotation marks for XPath anyway, he's escaping them for C#.  The actual, literal XPath is ListObject[@Title="SomeValue"]

Comment: You did not understand the quesion. The XPath syntax does NOT allow the backslash character for escaping.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by using `double quotes` instead of `single quotes` in the `XPath` expression.

For ex:

```
element.XPathSelectElements(String.Format("//group[@title=\"{0}\"]", "Man's"));
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem a while back and seemingly the simplest, but not the fastest solution is that you add a new node into the XML document that has an attribute with the value 'SomeValue', then look for that attribute value using a simple xpath search. After the you're finished with the operation, you can delete the "temporary node" from the XML document.

This way, the whole comparison happens "inside", so you don't have to construct the weird XPath query.

I seem to remember that in order to speed things up, you should be adding the temp value to the root node.

Good luck...

Comment: BTW, this solution might solve your problem, too, that pretty much states the same thing as you do:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642125/encoding-xpath-expressions-with-both-single-and-double-quotes

Comment: You did not understand the question.