# Variable in XPathSelectElement

Tags: c#, xml

I'm using XPathSelectElement to store data into an XML file. How can I in the code snippet below use a global variable name instead of id name 'City1'?

I want the code to be:

```
string myVariable = "City1"

XElement fname= country.XPathSelectElement("country/city/major[@id = myVariable]/firstname");
```

Thank you for your help

This is my XML:

```
<country>
  <city>
    <cityname>City1</cityname>
    <citynr>111</citynr>
    <person>
      <name>Person1</name>
      <name>Person2</name>
      <name>Person3</name>
      <name>Person4</name>
    </person>
    <major id=City1>
      <firstname>Major1firstname</firstname>
      <lastname>Major1lastname</lastname>
    </major>
  </city>
  <city>
    <cityname>City2</cityname>
    <citynr>222</citynr>
    <person>
      <name>Person5</name>
      <name>Person6</name>
      <name>Person7</name>
      <name>Person8</name>
    </person>
    <major id=City2>
      <firstname>Major2firstname</firstname>
      <lastname>Major2firstname</lastname>
    </major>
  </city>
</country>
```

Here is my code:

```
XDocument country= XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("myXML.xml"));

XElement fname= country.XPathSelectElement("country/city/major[@id = 'City1']/firstname");
XElement lname= country.XPathSelectElement("country/city/major[@id = 'City1']/lastname");

fname.Value = firstname.Text;
lname.Value = lastname.Text;

country.Save(Server.MapPath("myXML.xml"));
```

Comment: maybe `string.Format("country/city/major[@id = \"{0}\"]/firstname", myVariable)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are either looking for `string.Format` or the `StringBuilder` class.

```
fname= country.XPathSelectElement(string.Format("country/city/major[@id = '{0}']/firstname",myVariable));
```

references:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/fht0f5be(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/2839d5h5(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thank you!
I tried both 
[@id = '" + myVariable + "']
and
[@id = '{0}']/firstname", myVariable));

and they both worked!

Charlotte

Answer (score 3):

I'd just use the selection methods within LINQ to XML instead:

```
XElement fname = country.Element("country")
                        .Elements("city")
                        .Elements("major")
                        .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("id") == myVariable)
                        .Elements("firstname")
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

(By using `FirstOrDefault`, the result will be `null` if no such element is found.)

Comment: +1 Concatenating the ID into an XPath somewhat defeats the purpose of using Linq to XML, so I think this is the preferable approach if you're using Linq to XML in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

```
var fname = country
    .XPathSelectElement(
        "//country/city/major[@id = '" + myVariable + "']/firstname");
```

or

```
var fname = country
    .XPathSelectElement(
      String.Format("//country/city/major[@id = '{0}']/firstname", myVariable));
```

I believe that one way through which you might mitigate the XPath injection that @Tomalak mentions in the comment below is to use the `XName` type instead of string (exception handling left out of scope intently):

```
XName myVariable = "City1";
```

Comment: This approach would carry the risk of an injection vulnerability, if `myVariable` contained user input. A way to migrate that while keeping XPath as a selection method is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19513802/18771).

Comment: Putting the ID in an `XName` _would_ prevent XPath injection, but for all the wrong reasons, and it would prevent using IDs that could be entirely valid. Try using the ID `1234`. You'll encounter an exception when trying to assign the value to `myVariable`.