# XpathNavigator giving System.Xml.XPath.XPathException because of a single quote

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xpathnavigator

I have the following code

```
XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
XPathExpression expr;
expr = nav.Compile("//somePath/FieldData[@Location='Payer's Name']/@Value");
```

The single quote gives the exception System.Xml.XPath.XPathException. I have tried escaping it with a slash ('\'), ('), double single quotes. Nothing seems to work though. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: use `normalize-space`

Comment: I am sure it has nothing to do with a space

Comment: `string sUser = "U'1";
XmlNode xnUser = 
xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("tm:TM/tm:Admin/tm:User[@ID=\"" + sUser + "\"]", TMNamespaceManager);`

Comment: The xml node does not get selected with this.I get 0 results

Comment: what have you written show me?

Comment: expr = nav.Compile("//somePath/FieldData[@Location=\"" + "Payer's name" + "\"]/@Value")

Comment: string sUser = "Payer's name";
        expr = nav.Compile("//somePath/FieldData[@Location=\"" + sUser + "\"]/@Value")

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two ways to reliably handle this situation.

The first way is to define a `VariableContext` and put the value you want to use in an XPath variable. Then you can use an expression like:

```
//somePath/FieldData[@Location = $user]/@Value
```

I describe how to do that [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498192/xpath-injection-mitigation/19704008#19704008). It requires creating a `VariableContext` class as nothing suitable is built into .NET, but the example I provide should work as-is for most cases.

The other option is to use Linq-to-XML. If you go that route, you can query the node using Linq instead of XPath and delimiters are not an issue this way:

```
// here the doc variable is an XElement or XDocument
var value = (from fd in doc.Descendants("FieldData")
            where (string)fd.Attribute("Location") == sUser
            select fd.Attribute("Value")).FirstOrDefault();
```

or with the other Linq syntax:

```
var value = doc.Descendants("FieldData")
               .Where(fd => (string)fd.Attribute("Location") == sUser)
               .Select(fd => fd.Attribute("Value"))
               .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot have a space in the xpath "[@Location='Player's Name'] take the space out

Comment: A space causes no problems.I have used it with a space before

Comment: A space in a string constant is not a syntactic element and will not make any difference. The issue is clearly the apostrophe inside a string delimited by apostrophes, causing the parse to believe the string constant ends earlier than intended, and being unable to parse the following string fragment as a valid XPath, which of course, it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Note the single quote (trouble maker) has been replaced with a double quote.

`string sUser = "Payer's name"; // as per OP requirement considering only single quote
expr = nav.Compile("//somePath/FieldData[@Location=\"" + sUser + "\"]/@Value")`

Comment: So what if the variable contains a double quote instead? If you can guarantee this won't happen then this would work, but I'd definitely make sure it's documented that this is a precondition of this code fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you cannot use LINQ if you use language C#?

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class XmlParser
{
    public XDocument doc { get; set;}

    public XmlParser (XDocument doc)
    {
        this.doc = doc;
    }

    public List<XElement> searchElements (String elementName)
    {
        return doc.Elements(elementName).ToList<XElement>(); //this will search for all child nodes and return the elements with the specified name.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
expr = nav.Compile("//somePath/FieldData[@Location=\"Payer's Name\"]/@Value");
```