# How to select xml node from node data using c#

Tags: c#, xml

I  have an XML whose data looks like

```
<Chart>
<History>
<Master_Medication_List>
<Item1>
<ndcnumber>00121478105</ndcnumber>
</Item1>
</Master_Medication_List>
</History>
</Chart>
```

Now I  want to select node for that using this code

```
objEncList = objXml.SelectNodes("//Chart/History/Master_Medication_List/Item1/*[ndcnumber='" + strProductCode + "']");
```

but it's  not selecting any node.

Comment: is strProductCode is your ndcnumber right?

Comment: yes strProductCode = 00121478105

Comment: No its not case sensitive error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to select the element by content. `ndcnumber[.='content']` is how you do that. So either

```
objEncList = objXml.SelectNodes("
    //Chart/History/Master_Medication_List/Item1/ndcnumber[.='" + strProductCode + "']"
);
```

Or, if `objXml` is the actual root already, omit it:

```
objEncList = objXml.SelectNodes("
    /History/Master_Medication_List/Item1/ndcnumber[.='" + strProductCode + "']"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an element, so you would just access it like:

```
objEncList = objXml.SelectNodes("//Chart/History/Master_Medication_List/Item1/ndcnumber");
```

That is the node, the node's value is the actual value.

If you have multiple Item1s, I think you can select it via:

```
objEncList = objXml.SelectNodes("//Chart/History/Master_Medication_List/Item1/ndcnumber[text()='00121478105']");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to select all `<Item1>` elements with a nested `<ndcnumber>` element with value `00121478105`, you should do:

```
var itemList = objXml.SelectNodes("//Chart/History/Master_Medication_List/Item1[ndcnumber='" + strProductCode + "']");
```

If you are looking to select all `<ndcnumber>` elements with value `00121478105`, you should do:

```
var ndcnumberList = objXml.SelectNodes("//Chart/History/Master_Medication_List/Item1/ndcnumber[text()='" + strProductCode + "']");
```

(It is unclear from your question which you want.)

Notes:

- XPath queries are case sensitive, so you need to match the element name exactly.
- You have one too many levels in your query string: `Item1/*[ndcnumber=...` means "Look for any child of Item1 with a child named `ndcnumber` with a specific value.
- If `strProductCode` is a user-entered string, watch out for XPath injection attacks.  See [XPath injection mitigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498192/xpath-injection-mitigation) and [How to prevent XPath/XML injection in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381689/how-to-prevent-xpath-xml-injection-in-net).

Example [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0Re9RH).