# Infopath XML query from C#

Tags: c#, xml, infopath

I have included an XML file in my InfoPath form as a secondary data source. The data connection is named `Divisions`. Below is the structure and content of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Divisions>
    <Division>
        <Name>Business Application Services</Name>
        <Abbr>BAS</Abbr>
    </Division>
    <Division>
        <Name>Network Security Services</Name>
        <Abbr>NSS</Abbr>
    </Division>
    <Division>
        <Name>Back Office</Name>
        <Abbr>BO</Abbr>
    </Division>
</Divisions>
```

What I need to do is query this file using the `Abbr` of the division to get the `Name`.

I have used the following code to create a `XPathNodeIterator`:

```
XPathNodeIterator XPNIDivisions = this.DataSources["Divisions"].CreateNavigator().Select("/Divisions/Division/Name");
```

So now, how do I search for the name of the division whose `Abbr` is `'NSS'`? Or is the code I'm using wrong (I'm new to XML manipulation)?

Please note that these abbreviations and names could change (more could be added, or some could be deleted); so I need it to be dynamic, meaning that if I have the `Abbr` in a variable `MyAbbr`, I have to look for its `Name`.

Thanks in advance,

Yusuf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've been able to find a solution, and I must say it's a bit more complex than Roger's solution; you have to know a bit about [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/default.asp) expressions.

So what I had to do was just change the select from before

```
XPathNodeIterator XPNIDivisions = this.DataSources["Divisions"].CreateNavigator().Select("/Divisions/Division/Name");
```

to

```
XPathNodeIterator XPNIDivisions = this.DataSources["Divisions"].CreateNavigator().Select("/Divisions/Division[Abbr=\"thevalue\"]");
```

where `thevalue` is of course the value you're looking for.

In fact what I did was define a string variable

```
StrXPathDiv = "/Divisions/Division[Abbr=\"" + thevalue + "\"]";
```

and then pass it to the `Select()` method.

Then use the following code to get the value:

```
if (XPNIDivisions.MoveNext()) //If any record found
{
    XPNIDivisions.Current.MoveToChild(XPathNodeType.Element);
    XPNavMyDivision.SetValue(XPNIDivisions.Current.Value);
}
else { XPNavMyDivision.SetValue(""); }
```

where `XPNavMyDivision` is the navigator for where I need to set the value.

Thank you very much for your time and help Roger; I would have tried your solution if I were sure everyone had .NET 3.5 installed; however I'm quite sure of the opposite, so I had to stick with this.

Comment: Don't forget to escape apostrophes in thevalue - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341847/special-character-in-xpath-query

Comment: yep, that's what I did here:

    StrXPathDiv = "/Divisions/Division[Abbr=\"" + thevalue + "\"]";

with the `\"`

Answer (score 1):

Can you use Linq to Xml?
I was able to get this to work

```
string name = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml")
            .Descendants("Division")
            .Where(x => x.Element("Abbr").Value == "NSS")
            .First()
            .Element("Name")
            .Value;
```

Comment: Do I need anything specific to be able to use Linq to XML?
How is `XDocument` in your example?

Comment: You need to have .NET 3.5 or above - so that could be a deal breaker.
XDocument is Linq to Xml's version of XmlDocument.

Comment: `XDocument` is in the namespace and assembly `System.Xml.Linq`