# Filtering items in InfoPath selectNodes

Tags: c#, javascript, infopath-2007

I have an InfoPath 2007 form that uses selectNodes to chose a collection of items from my web service. So I have

```
<customer>
  <City>
  <State>
</customer>
```

In my code I have something like

```
customerData.selectNodes("tns:customer");
```

Of course this gives me all customers. But what if I want to filter out customers that live in a particular state? How can I modify my approach if I wanted to exclude all values of "FL" in the state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
 customerData.selectNodes("tns:customer[not(State = 'FL')]");
```

Note that if "FL" comes from some other string you may need to perform escaping ( [Special Character in XPATH Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341847/special-character-in-xpath-query) ).

I'd recommend reading on XPath, i.e. here are [some samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - this put me on the right track. But, to be clear, the actual answer ended up being: customerData.selectNodes("tns:customer[(tns:State != 'FL')]"); I'm not sure exactly why it differs in that way, but after modifying it for a bit, thats the answer that I needed.