# Escape single quote in XPath with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have an XPath query that looks like this, with both single and double quotes. How do I escape the apostrophe properly so that the query works?

I tried:

```
"//li[text()='Frank&apos;s car']"
```

but it doesn't seem to do it for me.

Any ideas?

```
 "//li[text()='Frank's car']"
```

Comment: I needed a similar solution for JS. Ended up using the grave accent, which then allows single and double quotes inside it. It's a quick (albeit not perfect) solution if you know you'll never need the grave accent within a string. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 45, accepted):

XPath doesn’t have any way of escaping special characters, so this is a little tricky. A solution in this specific case would be to use double quotes instead of single quotes in the XPath expression:

```
text()="Frank's car"
```

If you did this, you’d have to escape the quotes from Ruby if you used double quotes around the whole expression:

```
"//li[text()=\"Frank's car\"]"
```

You could use single quotes here if you aren’t doing any interpolation, and then escape the single quote:

```
'//li[text()="Frank\'s car"]'
```

A better option would perhaps be to make use of Ruby’s flexible quoting, so that none of the quotes would need escaping ,e.g.:

```
%{//li[text()="Frank's car"]}
```

Note that all the examples here doing escaping *in Ruby*, so that the string that reaches the XPath processor is `//li[text()="Frank's car"]`.

The more general case, when the text is variable that could contain single or double quotes is more difficult. XPath’s string literals can’t contain both types of quotes; you need to construct the string using the [XPath `concat` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-concat).

For example, if you wanted to match the string `"That's mine", he said.`, you would need to do something like:

```
text()=concat('"That', "'", 's mine", he said.')
```

And then you’d have to escape the quotes from Ruby (using `%{}` would be easiest).

I found [another question on SO dealing with this issue in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1341847/214790), and a [thread on the Nokogiri mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/nokogiri-talk/6stziv8GcJM), both of which might be worth looking at if you need to take this further.