# How to escape single quote in xpath 1.0 in selenium for python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code line used in selenium python script:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"//span[text()='" + cat2 + "']").click()
```

cat2 is variable from a database list that i get like this:

```
db = Database()
sql = "SELECT * FROM missing
listeproduit = db.select(sql)
for record in listeproduit:
    cat2       = record[6]
```

The probleme is when the variable contain a text like this:

```
cat2 = Debimetre d'air
```

Then the script don't works because it's an illegal xpath expression.

From my search, i understand that it's a problem with escaping the single quote in my variable cat2

From this answers :[Escape single quote in XPath with Nokogiri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822153/escape-single-quote-in-xpath-with-nokogiri)

They suggest to use concat() xpath function, but how to use it in my case ?
Thanks for your help.

Cheers

Comment: Did you try this - `cat2 = Debimetre d\'air` ?

Comment: @GirishSortur, XPath has a different escape mechanism.

Comment: I tried already this but as abel said xpath has a different escape mechanism.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In XPath 1.0, which is used by browsers and therefore by Selenium, there is no native way of escaping string literals (which was remedied in XPath 2.0). A [few workarounds are mentioned by this poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822153/escape-single-quote-in-xpath-with-nokogiri?lq=1), which includes:

- First off, make sure you understand the difference between escaping in Python, which is possible, and escaping within the XPath expression
- Then, if you simply need a single quote, surround it by double quotes, and vice versa
- Then, if one string literal contains both double and single quotes, use something like `concat('"', "Here's Johnny", '"', ", said Johnny.")`, which combines to the literal: `"Here's Johnny", said Johnny.`.

In your case, this would work:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"//span[text()=\"" + cat2 + "\"]").click()
```

Another way around this is to set an XPath variable to contain the value of your string literal, which helps in readability. But I couldn't find how to do it with the web drivers for Selenium, which typically means there is no such method available.

Comment: Works perfectly ! Anwser accepted. Thank you very much Able

Comment: Great answer! In fact the best I've seen regarding this issue, well done.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a Python function I've just wrote that escapes a string to use in an XPath 1.0 expression, using the trick described in @Abel's answer:

```
def escape_string_for_xpath(s):
    if '"' in s and "'" in s:
        return 'concat(%s)' % ", '\"',".join('"%s"' % x for x in s.split('"'))
    elif '"' in s:
        return "'%s'" % s
    return '"%s"' % s
```

Note that it adds the appropriate kind of quotes around your string, so be sure not to add extra quotes around the return value.

Usage example:

```
escaped_title = escape_string_for_xpath('"that\'ll be the "day"')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title=' + escaped_title + ']')
```