# Python Selenium, find text in span

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to find text on the page. Python code using Selenium:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@ng-bind=''@' + user.username']")
```

The text I need "@bassale" is on the page:

[image]

When executing the code, I get an error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //span[@ng-bind=''@' + user.username'] because of the following error:\nError: INVALID_EXPRESSION_ERR: DOM XPath Exception 51

Help me find this text on the page.

Comment: your xpath is not valid, because of which you are seeing issue

Comment: @thebadguy Ok, but how will I correctly compose the query?

Comment: try  "//span[@ng-bind=\"'@' + user.username\"]" just escaping quotes , reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759318/how-to-escape-single-quote-in-xpath-1-0-in-selenium-for-python

Comment: use driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@ng-bind=\"'@' + user.username\"]").text for getting the text

Comment: by.xpath('//span[@ng-bind="{0}"]'.format("'@' + user.username"));  or  by.xpath('//span[@ng-bind="\'@\' + user.username"]');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with something like this:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@ng-bind=\"'@' + user.username\"]")`