# Use Join Method to Combine Text of FirefoxWebElements

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm new to Python, so I was hoping somebody could help me out with the following issue.

```
project_tags = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@class, "campaignTags-tag")]')
separator = ', '
project_tags = separator.join(project_tags)
```

I know that if `project_tags` were an array, the `join` method would work. Hence I thought there may've been a chance the code above would've worked since `project_tags` is an iterable, but of course it didn't since it's an iterable of `FirefoxWebElements`.

I believe all I need to do in order to get `join` to work in this context is to point to the text of each `FirefoxWebElement`. **Even though I can accomplish the aim in a couple other ways, I was just curious if this is possible?**

One of those ways, which seems kind of verbose, is:

```
project_tags = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@class, "campaignTags-tag")]')
for idx, tag in enumerate(project_tags):
    if idx is 0:
        tags_string = tag.text
    else:
        tags_string = tags_string + ', ' + tag.text if idx < len(project_tags) else tags_string + tag.text
```

**Are there any methods I might not know about that would allow me to refactor and minimize the working example above?**

Comment: I wouldn't say it was verbose; I would say it is not valid Python.

Comment: @ScottHunter not valid, why?? (i've edited my answer btw and fixed the syntax error)

Comment: You fixed it, and have to ask why?

Comment: @ScottHunter thought you may have been referring to something else........... is that all you came here to say? lol

Comment: You can try using the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759318/how-to-escape-single-quote-in-xpath-1-0-in-selenium-for-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this does what you want:

```
tags_string = ", ".join([t.text for t in project_tags])
```

Note, however, that it includes a comma between the last 2 tags, which your code does not, which I believe is a bug.  If not, you could use:

```
tags_string = ", ".join([t.text for t in project_tags[:-1]]) + project_tags[-1].text
```

Comment: i realized it was a bug, but i'm so confused why `idx + 1 < len(project_tags)` doesn't work properly? for instance, if you had a list of 3 items, the first iteration triggers the first clause of the if statement since `idx` is `0`; for the second iteration, because `idx + 1` is `2` and `len(list)` is `3`, the first half of the "ternary" operator should be triggered, but instead it resolves to the `else` of the "ternary" operator??? why

Comment: For the last iteration, `idx` = `len(project_tags)-1`, which means `idx+1` = `len(project_tags)`, and thus `idx+1 < len(project_tags)` is false.

Comment: precisely... that's what i would expect to happen, but for some reason `idx+1 < len(project_tags)` was resolving to false for the last 2 iterations, so that you would end up with output like this: `rock, hip-hoprap` or `oranges, bananasapples`

Comment: That is the output you get if the expression is false in only the last iteration, which is in fact what was happening.

Comment: huh? there's no comma between `bananas` and `oranges` or `hip-hop` and `rap` because `idx+1 < len(project_tags)` is necessarily resolving to false for the last two inputs of each concatenation process. that's what's confusing me: why does it resolve to false for the last two inputs instead of just the very last input?