# How can I use XPath to find an element with a title that contains single and double quotes?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, attributes, escaping

I have some Python/Selenium code that finds an element with the specified title text using XPath:

```
tab_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="' + tab_title + '"]'))
```

It works fine in most cases, but it fails when it encounters an element with a title that contains double quotes.

```
<p title="that'll be the &quot;dayg&quot;">That'll be the "day"</p>
```

So, that leaves me with two questions:

1. How can I make it work with title values that contain double quotes?
2. How can I make it work with any title value, such as ones that contain both double and single quotes?

Comment: As pointed by Michael Key, this should work for both single and double quotes :`//p[contains(@title,concat('"',''))]|//p[contains(@title,"'")]`. First part is for double, second for single.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Elias's XPath escaping function from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47461052/1741346).

```
def escape_string_for_xpath(s):
    if '"' in s and "'" in s:
        return 'concat(%s)' % ", '\"',".join('"%s"' % x for x in s.split('"'))
    elif '"' in s:
        return "'%s'" % s
    return '"%s"' % s

escaped_title = escape_string_for_xpath('"that\'ll be the "day"')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title=' + escaped_title + ']')
```

Answer (score 0):

For XPath 1.0 the rule is:

(a) a string literal can't contain the mark used as the string delimiter; the only way around that is to form the string using concat(), for example `concat("'", '"', "'")` is the string of three characters `'"'`.

(b) if a string literal contains a character that has special meaning in the host language (e.g. `"` in Java or `&` in XML) then it needs to be escaped using the host language escaping conventions (`\"` in Java, `&amp;` in XML).

In XPath 2.0 you can get around (a) by doubling: for example `""""` is a string literal representing a string of length one containing a double-quotes character. You can also get around both (a) and (b) by using the `codepoints-to-string()` function.