# XML attributes with single quotes using XML R package

Tags: r, xml, xpath

I am trying to find the value of nodes associated with attributes that are described using single quotes using the R package XML.  For example, a node A has an attribute `Name="Hello 'World'"`.

I create a character vector

```
s = "//A[@Name='Hello 'World'']"
```

and then use xpathApply(top,s,xmlValue) to try to get the information.  I get an xpath error because the single quotes end the attribute string prematurely.  Does anyone have a suggestion.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
library(XML)
top <- xmlParse('<A Name="Hello \'World\'">foo</A>')
```

You can do `s <- "//A[@Name=\"Hello 'World'\"]"` or `s <- '//A[@Name=concat("Hello ", "\'World\'")]'` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822153/escape-single-quote-in-xpath-with-nokogiri)) to get

```
xpathApply(top,s,xmlValue)
# [[1]]
# [1] "foo"
```