# How to locate an element using an xpath that contains an apostrophe

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to locate an element, which is a textbox that contains hint text:

```
<textarea placeholder="What's going on?"><textarea>
```

Here's what I have tried, which is not working.

```
@FindBy(xpath="//textarea[@placeholder='What\'s going on?']")
public WebElement inputBox;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape single quote in XPath with Nokogiri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822153/escape-single-quote-in-xpath-with-nokogiri)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
@FindBy(xpath="//textarea[@placeholder=\"What's going on?\"]")
```

It escapes the surrounding quotes so it can handle the quote correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below xpath :

```
 //textarea[contains(@placeholder, "What's going on?")]
```