# xpath contains() doesn't work if text contains '

Tags: xpath

```
//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text,'South Korea's')]
```

doesn't work, gives below parsing error

```
org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor.XPathParserException: CUP parser error: Parser error: line 1 col 55: s
```

However `//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text,'South Korea')]`  works, when I remove `'s` from `'South Korea's'`

How to handle this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape single quote in XPath with Nokogiri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822153/escape-single-quote-in-xpath-with-nokogiri)

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to use an XPath 2.0 implementation, the notation described in https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-literals to double single or double quotes in XPath string literals should work e.g. `@text,'South Korea''s')`. Of course double quote as delimiters e.g. `@text,"South Korea's")` should also do, just make sure you do any encoding the host language (e.g. Java) requires for the double quotes if the XPath expression is a string in that host language.