# Upgraded to php 8.1 now getting "PHP Deprecated: addslashes()"

Tags: php

I just upgraded to php 8.1 from 7.3 and going through to resolve a handful of stuff that broke.  One message that pops up is "PHP Deprecated:  addslashes()".  We use the command quite a bit, and it's not to prevent mysql injections.  We have to deal with names that could have special characters in them ' ~ etc.

But when I check out https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php
it says that it is supported in PHP8.

Sorry, I guess the newb in me... but what am I missing?
If it's out, ok, what is the supported way for dealing with it now?

**Update to add code example and question clarification**

Now that I've slept on it, I see it's not a deprecation error on addslashes(). It's an error saying that the value that we are passing into the function is NULL.  And I see in the docs this is no longer allowed as of 8.1.

So based on that information what is the new and improved way handle the example below.

```
$(function () {
$('.adminheader').html('<?php addslashes(GetMainEventNames()); ?>');
$('.maineventbuttons').button().each(function () {
  var MainEventCode = $(this).attr('data-code');
          $(this).click(function () {
            ChangeLocalActiveStatus(MainEventCode);
          });
      });
```

**Error Message**

```
PHP Deprecated:  addslashes(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated in....
```

Comment: `addslashes()` has never been the right tool for any job. If you can provide an example of where you're using it, I guarantee I (or somebody else here) can provide a better alternative

Comment: Can you share an example of the error message in full? `addslashes()` has not been marked for deprecation as you noted and there's no errors here ~ https://3v4l.org/TFMoY#v8.1.3

Comment: added examples, error messages and I see now it's not about addslashes being deprecated.  It's that the value cannot be null.

Comment: `addslashes` is, as Phil said, the wrong tool for the job here. `json_encode` would make more sense.

Comment: "Passing null to parameter #1 (...) is deprecated" - why not fix that?

Comment: @Quentin why json_encode? I think the method where the php output is being used takes an html string

Comment: @Don'tPanic — It's generating a JavaScript string. The JavaScript then generates HTML from it.

Comment: @Phil I have a use for addslashes()  I need to create an import file from sql query. 
Yes there are other ways to solve the solution; That doesn't change the fact that I have a valid use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So your PHP function `GetMainEventNames()` is returning `null` at least sometimes. Is this expected or desired behaviour? If it is then there are two possible solutions. One is for your function to check if the return value is null and return an empty string instead. The other is to use the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) inside your `addslashes()` function like this:

```php
<?php addslashes(GetMainEventNames() ?? ''); ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

***Addslashes is never the right answer***

to address your specific code,

```
$('.adminheader').html('<?php addslashes(GetMainEventNames()); ?>');
```

should be replaced with

```
$('.adminheader').html(<?php echo json_encode(htmlentities(GetMainEventNames(), ENT_QUOTES|ENT_SUBSTITUTE|ENT_DISALLOWED),JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR); ?>);
```

and generally speaking,

if you need to escape HTML, it's (unfortunately)

```
echo htmlentities($html, ENT_QUOTES|ENT_SUBSTITUTE|ENT_DISALLOWED);
```

if you need to quote shell arguments, it's

```
$cmd.= " --file=" . escapeshellarg($arg);
```

if you need to quote SQL strings it's

```
$sql.= "WHERE col = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($str)."'";
```

or

```
$sql.= "WHERE col = " . $pdo->quote($str);
```

if you need to quote javascript/json strings its

```
let str = <?=json_encode($str, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);?>;
```

if you need to quote a string in xpath it's

```
//based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/1352556/1067003
function xpath_quote(string $value):string{
    if(false===strpos($value,'"')){
        return '"'.$value.'"';
    }
    if(false===strpos($value,'\'')){
        return '\''.$value.'\'';
    }
    // if the value contains both single and double quotes, construct an
    // expression that concatenates all non-double-quote substrings with
    // the quotes, e.g.:
    //
    //    concat("'foo'", '"', "bar")
    $sb='concat(';
    $substrings=explode('"',$value);
    for($i=0;$i<count($substrings);++$i){
        $needComma=($i>0);
        if($substrings[$i]!==''){
            if($i>0){
                $sb.=', ';
            }
            $sb.='"'.$substrings[$i].'"';
            $needComma=true;
        }
        if($i < (count($substrings) -1)){
            if($needComma){
                $sb.=', ';
            }
            $sb.="'\"'";
        }
    }
    $sb.=')';
    return $sb;
}
$xp->query('/catalog/items/item[title='.xpath_quote($var).']');
```

if you need to quote strings in CSS its

```
// CSS escape code ripped from Zend Framework ( https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Escaper/Escaper.php )
function css_escape_string($string)
{
    $cssMatcher = function ($matches) {
        $chr = $matches[0];
        if (strlen($chr) == 1) {
            $ord = ord($chr);
        } else {
            $chr = mb_convert_encoding($chr, 'UTF-16BE', 'UTF-8'); // $this->convertEncoding($chr, 'UTF-16BE', 'UTF-8');
            $ord = hexdec(bin2hex($chr));
        }
        return sprintf('\\%X ', $ord);
    };
    $originalEncoding = mb_detect_encoding($string);
    if ($originalEncoding === false) {
        $originalEncoding = 'UTF-8';
    }
    ;
    $string = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', $originalEncoding); // $this->toUtf8($string);
                                                                        // throw new Exception('mb_convert_encoding(\''.$string.'\',\'UTF-8\',\''.$originalEncoding.'\');');
    if ($string === '' || ctype_digit($string)) {
        return $string;
    }
    $result = preg_replace_callback('/[^a-z0-9]/iSu', /*$this->*/$cssMatcher, $string);
    // var_dump($result);
    return mb_convert_encoding($result, $originalEncoding, 'UTF-8'); // $this->fromUtf8($result);
}
```

***at no point is addslashes ever the right answer***, and (mis)using it can lead to security exploits.

Comment: Looks like op wants actual HTML so using `htmlentities()` is the wrong thing here

Comment: @Phil ... you think OP was running html through addslashes? that makes no sense! would turn `<a href="url">click me</a>` into `<a href=\"url\">click me</a>`

Comment: They were using `addslashes` to insert a string of HTML into a JavaScript single-quoted string. Using `json_encode()` is the right answer

Comment: Quoting SQL substitutions is also _"never the right answer"_