# Get an element by using it's attribute value

Tags: javascript

I need to retrieve an element in an html document. I can't update the html so I can't add a class or an id. And the class used here can pobliby be used in another place in the code. Here is the element :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="M'affecter cette demande" data-aura-rendered-by="1314:0" class="forceActionLink" data-aura-class="forceActionLink">
      <div class="slds-truncate" title="M'affecter cette demande" data-aura-rendered-by="1315:0">M'affecter cette demande</div>
</a>
```

So I want to retrieve the `<a>` element, by using the `title` attribute. 
In javascript I try that :

```
var bouton = document.querySelector("[title = \'M'affecter cette demande\']");
```

But I got an error :

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[title = 'M'affecter cette demande']' is not a valid selector.

How can I retrieve this element ?

Comment: You don't need the backslashes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425637/xpath-attribute-quoting-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this selector instead: `[title="M\'affecter cette demande"]`

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('[title="M\'affecter cette demande"]');

console.log(elem);
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="M'affecter cette demande" data-aura-rendered-by="1314:0" class="forceActionLink" data-aura-class="forceActionLink">
      <div class="slds-truncate" title="M'affecter cette demande" data-aura-rendered-by="1315:0">M'affecter cette demande</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use this selector:

```js
var a = document.querySelector('a[title="M\'affecter cette demande"]');
console.log(a);
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="M'affecter cette demande" data-aura-rendered-by="1314:0" class="forceActionLink" data-aura-class="forceActionLink">
  <div class="slds-truncate" title="M'affecter cette demande" data-aura-rendered-by="1315:0">M'affecter cette demande</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using double quotes ":**

you'll have to escape the inner double quotes:

```
"[title = \"M'affecter cette demande\"]"
```

**Using single quotes ':**

you'll have to escape the inner single quote:

```
'[title = "M\'affecter cette demande"]'
```

**Using template literal `:**

you don't have to escape anything:

```
`[title = "M'affecter cette demande"]`
```