# Using quotes in Xpath

Tags: c#, xpath, special-characters, quotes

Say if I need to use an XPath expression as follows

```
v:MapLink[@Entity='TOM'S RESTAURANT']
```

But an exception is thrown because of the quote in TOM'S.

Is there a way around this?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encoding XPath Expressions with both single and double quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642125/encoding-xpath-expressions-with-both-single-and-double-quotes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

presumably this is all inside a string itself, so would this work?

```
"v:MapLink[@Entity=\"TOM'S RESTAURANT\"]"
```

Comment: Good call; I hadn't noticed the [c#] tag.

Answer (score 2):

Just use different quotes around the attribute:

```
v:MapLink[@Entity="TOM'S RESTAURANT"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the "other" quote (quote vs. apostrophe) inside a string in an XPath expression, as shown in the other answers.

If you have a literal containing both, you can use the `concat()` function like this:

```
Tom's "Napoli" Pizza
```

as literal in an XPath expression would become

```
concat("Tom's ", '"Napoli" Pizza')
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the above; plus, in XPath 2.0 you can use the SQL convention of doubling the delimiting quote. So you can write

```
"Tom's ""Nopoli"" Pizza"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, for example a searching element XPath in 2 Forms :

```
(1) Parameters/Parameter[Key="{0}"]

(2) Parameters/Parameter[Key='{0}']
```

When `{0} = CCC[AAA="BBB"]DDD`

The first form will get error, and the second form which make the quotes ' , " different will work.

That is

```
// All using " Get Error
Parameters/Parameter[Key="CCC[AAA="BBB"]DDD"] 

// Using ' Out,  and " In  Work
Parameters/Parameter[Key='CCC[AAA="BBB"]DDD']
```