# Using double quotes instead of single quotes in DOMXpath query fails

Tags: php, dom

This might just be a problem with the php syntax, but why does this work:

```
$b = new DOMXPath($z);
$b = $x->query('//div[contains(@class,"xxx")]');
```

but using double quotes with single inside does not:

```
$b = $x->query("//div[contains(@class,'xxx')]//a");
```

Comment: Are you sure? Actually both on the Xpath as on the PHP side this should not make a difference. Probaly the added `//a` makes the difference here? See as well [Encoding XPath Expressions with both single and double quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/642125/367456).

Comment: no that was added by mistake in the question. without the a it doesn't work

Comment: Most xpath examples are with single quotes, which would be your variant that does *not* work. Please really double-check you don't have some other issue here. It's highly likely. Welcome to Stack Overflow by the way.

Comment: Can you provide a minimum example of HTML and PHP code that demonstrates how this does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has something to do with the single quote inside the string.

Try this:

```
$b = $x->query("//div[contains(@class,\"xxx\")]//a");
```

Otherwise I would just stick to the single quote version. Whats the big deal anyway?