# Encoding XPath string in SelectChildNode having both single and double quotes in C++

Tags: c++, xpath, for-xml-path

I have been trying to pass a string to fetch the node and am successful for string with only single quote (') and only double quotes ("). But am unable to parse it when string contains both singe and double quotes. I have my string in CString as-

```
CString str=L("H'el"lo");
```

and all other combinations of these. Can you please tell me how to do in C++, i have seen the examples are in C# but that are not helping me out.

Here's the link for C# [Encoding XPath Expressions with both single and double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642125/encoding-xpath-expressions-with-both-single-and-double-quotes)

```
XmlNode n = doc.SelectSingleNode(“/root/emp[lname=" + str + "]“);
```

How should i make my str work for string containing both single and double quotes in any order.